# Using webcam in Facebook webview

Tags: facebook, webview, webcam

I have a webpage which calls getUsermedia (we use a widely used polyfill). OK on android.
If I open my page from my Facebook app via a url, it does not work. 
I mean, getuserMedia is not available. Why is a big question since debugging the webview seems tricky at least.
From what I read, the webview should be Chrome (version?) +V8.
I guess it is because the user cannot accept the cam access?
Any hint?
Thanks a lot,
Michaël

Comment: Most likely turned off on purpose. At least it is not possible to do that

Comment: Seems inapp browser is a mess: http://www.howtogeek.com/239363/forget-the-facebook-app-use-the-mobile-site-for-a-less-annoying-experience/